# How to implement instance counter in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was learning es6 so I was trying to convert these code from es5 to es6.

I knew how to make an instance counter in es5. The `id` built on `A.prototype` and `counter` built on `A` itself. When I built a instance by `A`, it will trigger `counter++` to set `id`. Thus, it implements `inheritance counter` of action.

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.id = ++A.counter;
        console.log(this.id);
    }
    A.counter = 0;
    return A;
}());
a = new A();  // 1
b = new A();  // 2
c = new A();  // 3
```

If I worked in es6, how do I implement same feature?

Comment: `id` is not built on `A.prototype`, but on each A instance.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20%2B%2BA.counter%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0AA.counter%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(a.id%2C%20b.id)

Answer (score 8):

The other two answers are completely correct. But if you wanted to get super crazy ES6 you could make getters for the properties.

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this._id = A.counter;
        console.log(this.id);
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    static get counter() {
        A._counter = (A._counter || 0) + 1;
        return A._counter;
    }
}

a = new A() // <- 1
b = new A() // <- 2
c = new A() // <- 3
```

That way your counter and id are both read only, and your counter increments automatically every time you access it...plus it's all tidy inside the class definition instead of needing to go outside it.

Not saying you need to do it this way...but it seems like you're learning about ES6 and this example shows a couple of neat tricks about what you can do with it.

Answer (score 3):

You'd do it in exactly the same way as in ES5:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.id = ++A.counter;
        console.log(this.id);
    }
}
A.counter = 0;
var a = new A();  // 1
var b = new A();  // 2
var c = new A();  // 3
```

(you can also add the same unnecessary IIFE if you want)

Answer (score 3):

The es6 `class` can complete you wanted.

`id` isn't built on `A.prototype`, but on each A instance. The `constructor` is to do a instance. So you can look, it does `this.id = ++A.counter` when class A is built a new instance.

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        this.id = ++A.counter;
        console.log(this.id)
    }
}
A.counter = 0;

a = new A()
b = new A()
c = new A()
```

Comment: That's a syntax error in ES6. The `static` keyword is for methods only.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which is also fully contained in an ES6 class as BryanGrezeszak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36855371/8213890) but with a different behavior that may be useful in some cases:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.constructor.counter = (this.constructor.counter || 0) + 1;
    this._id = this.constructor.counter;
    console.log(this.id);
  }
  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }
}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

a = new B(); // <- 1
b = new C(); // <- 1
c = new B(); // <- 2
d = new A(); // <- 1
```

The difference with this code is that inherited classes have their own independent counter.

If you don't want to add properties to the constructor, you can replace

```
this.constructor.counter
```

with

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).counter
```

that is the current way of expressing the deprecated

```
this.__proto__.counter
```

That way `counter` will be a static property of the class rather than a property of the (static function) `constructor`.